# Is the set of all cycles of length 4 is linearily independent in a graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Consider all the cycles of length 4 in a graph which doesn't contain cycles of length less than 4 (and odd cycles either) and a matrix $A$ in which $a_{ij}=1$ if the $i$th 4-member cycle contains the $j$th edge, else $a_{ij}=0$. Are the rows of the matrix $A$ linearly independent?

Comment: Have you checked directly for some (small, complete) bipartite graphs? Those are the graphs with the cycle structure you describe.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the graph $C_8 \times C_8$.  Think of this as a chess board drawn on a torus by gluing the opposite sides of the board to one another, where the vertices are the corners of the squares and the edges are the edges of the squares.

Now clearly the sum of the column vectors corresponding to the black squares is just the vector of all ones, since each edge is adjacent to one black square. But of course the same holds for the white squares, so the sum of the black squares equals the sum of the white squares and we have a linear dependency.

Comment: What represents $C_{8}×C_{8}$? Could you please present the matrix?

Comment: $C_8$ is a cycle of length 8, $\times$ denotes the cartesian product of graphs.  $C_8 \times C_8$ is as I described, the graph defined by a chessboard where the edges of the squares are now edges of the graph but with a gluing rule that says if you go off one side of the board you come back on the opposite side. The matrix is a $64 \times 128$ matrix, so no I am not going to write it down.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be the cycles of length $4$ in a graph. Per your definition, the cycles of length $4$ are linearly dependent if and only if there exists a nonzero function $f: C \to \mathbb{R}$ such that on every edge $e$ we have $\sum_{e \in C} f(C) = 0$.

Then it becomes clear that Nate's answer is correct. In fact if you take the $5 \times 5$ grid, and glue the top edge to the bottom and left edge to the right, then we see the $4$ cycles exactly correspond to cells in our grid. We can assign $\pm1$ to each cycle in a checkerboard fashion. Since we glued the boundaries we have each edge is part of exactly two 4 cycles, and by our assignment one of these has $+1$ and the other $-1$. Thus the cycles are linearly dependent.

Comment: Could you please present a picture what cycles you think of in the 5×5 grid?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGOVM.png

Comment: This graph has 16 4-cycles and no smaller cycles/odd cycles.

Comment: Could I skip somehow the linearly dependent 4-member cycles in an exhaustive search for only the cycles of length 4? Can I easily decide if a 4-cycle is dependent on the found ones?

Answer (score 0):

See the full graph with n vertices.

Count of cycles of length 4 is more when count of edges.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say that my graphs cannot contain cycles of length less than 4 (and odd cycles either). Could you please show a counterexample for the dependency?